# Python server for hardware control (possibly with Twisted?)

Tags: python, twisted

I'm currently in the process of programming a server which can let clients interact with a piece of hardware. For the interested readers it's a device which monitors the wavelength of a set of lasers concurrently (and controls the lasers). The server should be able to broadcast the wavelengths (a list of floats) on a regular basis and let the clients change the settings of the device through dll calls.

My initial idea was to write a custom protocol to handle the communication, but after thinking about how to handle TCP fragmentation and data encoding I bumped into Twisted, and it looks like most of the work is already done if I use perspective broker to share the data and call server methods directly from the clients. This solution might be a bit overkill, but for me it appeared obvious, what do you think?

My main concern arrose when I thought about the clients. Basically I need two types of clients, one which just displays the wavelengths (this should be straight forward) and a second which can change the device settings and get feedback when it's changed. My idea was to create a single client capable of both, but thinking about combining it with our previous system got me thinking... The second client should be controlled from an already rather complex python framework which controls a lot of independant hardware with relatively strict timing requirements, and the settings of the wavelengthmeter should then be called within this sequential code. Now the thing is, how do I mix this with the Twisted client? As I understand Twisted is not threadsafe, so I can't simply spawn a new thread running the reactor and then inteact with it from my main thread, can I?

Any suggestions for writing this server/client framework through different means than Twisted are very welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start the reactor in a dedicated thread, and then issue calls to it with [`blockingCallFromThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.internet.threads.html#blockingCallFromThread) from your existing "sequential" code.

Also, I'd recommend [AMP](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.protocols.amp.html) for the protocol rather than PB, since AMP is more amenable to heterogeneous environments ([see amp-protocol.net for independent protocol information](http://amp-protocol.net/)), and it sounds like you have a substantial amount of other technology you might want to integrate with this system.

Comment: I've now had some time to look at AMP, and I believe your right, it's very suited for this project. I managed to get a server and client running, so now I'll see if I can get the blockingCall working as you suggested. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/)?

It's a library that simplifies working with sockets. It can operate over TCP and implements several topologies, such as publisher/subscriber (for broadcasting data, such as your laser readings) and request/response (that you can use for you control scheme).

There are bindings for several languages and the site is full of examples. Also, it's amazingly fast.

Good stuff.